# How can I create a new environment for equations?

Tags: equations, environments, tcolorbox, counters

I'm trying to create a new environment, more specifically using a `\newtcolorbox[]{}{}{}`. My intention is to create an environment that brings together both the `\begin{tcolorbox}[] \end{tcolorbox}` and the `\begin{equation} \end{equation}` in order to make it easier to use. I want to create an environment called `answer` with the following features from the tcolorbox package:

```
\newtcolorbox[]{answer}{%
    enhanced,
    center,
    breakable,
    boxrule = 0pt,
    frame hidden,
    hbox,
    colback = myblack!80,
    sharp corners,
    rounded corners = southeast,
    rounded corners = northeast,
    rounded corners = southwest,
    rounded corners = northwest,
    arc is angular,
    arc = 3mm,
    coltext = white,
    math upper,
}
```

I was able to create the box for it to turn all inputs into mathematical outputs, however, I also wanted to be able to reference the equations within these boxes, so that if I typed:

```
\begin{answer}\label{eq: 1}
     A random equation
\end{answer}
```

Could I reference this equation such that the counter follows the same counter from the equation or align environment. I tried to include on the initial options `[use counter from = equation]`, but it doesn`t work.

I have this:
[image]

but I need something like this (I made it in Photoshop):
[image]

Comment: Instead of `use counter from` use `use counter=equation`, the `use counter from` is meant to inherit the counter from other `tcolorbox`es, whereas `use counter` is meant to use a standard LaTeX counter (like `equation`).

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: You also don't specify any place where the counter is output.

Comment: And you don't show any minimal example which we can compile...

Comment: Now, I specify what I want

Comment: What is your minimal complete code to process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\tcbhighmath{...}` to highlight your formula:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{answer}{
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath[
         boxrule = 0pt,
         frame hidden,
         colback = black!80,
         sharp corners,
         rounded corners = southeast,
         rounded corners = northeast,
         rounded corners = southwest,
         rounded corners = northwest,
         arc is angular,
         arc = 3mm,
         coltext = white,
     ]{\BODY}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{answer}\label{eq:1}
A random equation
\end{answer}

A random equation in \eqref{eq:1}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nowadays I'd probably use `\NewDocumentEnvironment{answer}{b}` (and then `#1` instead of `\BODY`) instead of `environ`, else good answer.